# Reputation tab shows +30, +40, +50, +60, +70, +80, +90, +100, +110, each as an individual event for one day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history

I decided to check my reputation tab on MSE, and saw this:

[image]

What is with the +30, +40, +50, +60, +70, +80, +90, +100, +110?

Comment: x-site duplicate (MSO): [Reputation tab bug: Single event duplicated arbitrary amount of times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416176/reputation-tab-bug-single-event-duplicated-arbitrary-amount-of-times)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, this one is consecutive summations for each event, the linked one is simply duplicated events.

Comment: It's probably the same display bug. Instead of the actual title, the newest event of this day is shown. Is it necessary to keep two communities occupied with this?

Comment: I'm seeing something similar https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxh7x.png and it looks like the color of the summary is messed up. I got down votes in there somewhere, but they aren't listed.

Comment: @ColleenV something is messed up here, the screenshot shows repeated votes at the same time , which is very unlikely that it happened, right :), btw.: I see the same when I look at my rep tab

Comment: it's all the same bug, a broken view was released. At least they're fixing what was previously a pretty problematic design to begin with

Comment: @Vickel Yeah, and we just lost comment excerpts from our "all actions tab". Pretty sure something escaped the dev servers and made itself a nest in prod.

Comment: This is an item index issue that slipped through the cracks. We have a fix in the works. Expect it to be resolved in the next 24 hours. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the process of updating the layout for the Activity Reputation page, a bug was introduced that replicated the *first* reputation entry for a given item for each reputation change instead of the appropriate one. I've shipped a fix network-wide.

---

[Comment posted before shipping the fix for further context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376538/reputation-tab-shows-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100-110-each-as-an-i#comment1255049_376538):

> This is an item index issue that slipped through the cracks. We have a fix in the works. Expect it to be resolved in the next 24 hours. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Something like `item[0]` instead of `item[i]`. Ah, how many times I do this... :P

Comment: Yep @richardec, that was basically the exact problem. It can be soooo easy to miss!

Comment: It's all fixed now, thanks a ton! By the way, if it isn't too much trouble, can you please edit the [status-completed] tag into [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416176/13552470) post too *(because it is)*?

Comment: There is still an issue in my profile  with the summation of the reputation. On Feb 17 I got a total of +128, but when I expand it, I see +140 in red (the individual events have been corrected) https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxh7x.png Maybe I’m interpreting it incorrectly, but I don’t think +# should ever be color coded red. Is it something that has been corrected going forward and my history is just going to stay wonky?

Comment: @ColleenV https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376557/1136431 (and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376550/1136431)