# Display Bug in Reputation history? Repeating Rows .

Tags: bug, reputation-history

Today I looked in my reputation history and saw nearly everywhere "repeating" lines.

See screenshot below:
[image]

Is this a known issue?

**As everybody can see in the screenshot, the manifestation of the problem is different then in [Reputation tab shows +30, +40, +50, +60, +70, +80, +90, +100, +110, each as an individual event for one day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376538/reputation-tab-shows-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100-110-each-as-an-i). If it has the same root cause or not. Why on heavens earth does everybody want to delete this question? Hiding a bug?**

Comment: If you compare the pictures, then this is not a dupe! And it does of course not solve my question

Comment: @V2Blast Presumably, since you closed this, this is indeed the same bug as the one causing the effect in the dupe?

Comment: @zcoop98: Ah, at a glance, it looked like it was the same issue being reported. That said, it looks like a dev has just commented on the [linked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376538/335251) to note that the cause has been identified: "This is an item index issue that slipped through the cracks. We have a fix in the works. Expect it to be resolved in the next 24 hours. Thanks for the report!" I'll leave it to the community to determine whether this post should be reopened or not.

Comment: On the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71111430/3648282), if you did edit 4 answers, they were all deleted; you didn't edit the question. Is that the correct post?

Comment: This really does look like it's the same bug _and_ [it appears to be fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJBFX.png). I'm not sure why the question was reopened.

Comment: Your question is not deleted, it is closed. Those are different things.