# Accepted answers are no longer highlighted uniquely in new reputation history page

Tags: bug, reputation, design, accepted-answer, reputation-history

In the new reputation history page, accepted answers are no longer highlighted specially. There used to be a green background on events which included an accepted answer. You can see this the previous "new" design in a screenshot on [another of my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372649/1136431).

[image]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376538/reputation-tab-shows-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100-110-each-as-an-i

Comment: @Vickel how exactly is this related? That post is about repeating items - this is about a quality of the a specific type of event. Because the correct values are shown for accepts (e.g. 35), but they're just formatted not as they used to be.

Comment: well, I meant related to the whole new UI. I should have better linked this one of yours: [Bugs in the new rep history page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376544/bugs-in-the-new-rep-history-page), I guess